# If you call somebody or they call you, what is the name for that person?

Tags: single-word-requests

This can also be applied to client-server interactions (which is what I need it for).

For example, if you (the client) send data to the server or retrieve data from the server, what is the name of the server in that instance?

Or, if the server sends data to the client or the server receives data from the client, what is the name of the client in that instance?

Both of these names should be equivalent. Basically, I'm looking for a word (or words) for the *other* person/entity when the two are connected.

Comment: Would *sender* and *receiver* not do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Interlocutor
- The other computer
- The remote computer

Answer (score 2):

Besides previously-suggested *sender, receiver,* and *interlocutor*, consider *[respondent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Respondent)* or *other party*.  In current usage, *[correspondent](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=correspondent)* apparently refers mostly to news media reporters vs. someone being communicated with.  I've seen *co-communicator* used, and it may technically satisfy your need, but probably is not a recognized word.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title, if you are the *caller*, then the person you are calling is the *callee*.  While this might be awkward in English, it's common in telecommunications discussions.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it 'the sender' and 'the recipient'. Starting by saying 'the sending server' and 'the receiving server'. Then use sender and recipient.